# Cached RODBC odbcConnect() in R fails after odbcCloseAll()

Tags: sql, r, caching

I'm pretty much using the code posted by Joe Cheng and Aaron Mackey [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/shiny-discuss/globalenv/shiny-discuss/0VjQc2a6z3M/krQiKaRSlk8J) for a cached SQL connection in R. It works fine until I call `odbcCloseAll()` and then try to call `getConnection()` again. So here's what I'm doing step-by-step:

1. Call `getConnection()` - this works as expected
2. Call `odbcCloseAll()` - just to see what would happen if somehow all connections are closed
3. Call `getConnection()` - this is where I get an error

> Error in

```
odbcClose(.connection) : argument is not an open RODBC channel  
3 stop("argument is not an open RODBC channel")  
2 odbcClose(.connection)  
1 getConnection()
```

It is not until I call `rm(list=ls(all.names = TRUE))` and source the `getConnection()` function into R again that I get the error message to go away.

The code I have is provided below:

```js
library(RODBC)

getConnection <- function() {
  
  if (!exists('.connection', where=.GlobalEnv)) {
    .connection <<- odbcConnect("myDsn")
  } else if (class(try(sqlQuery(.connection, "SELECT 1"))) == "try-error") {
    odbcClose(.connection)
    .connection <<- odbcConnect("myDsn")
  }
  
  return(.connection)
}
```

**Question:** I don't understand why `getConnection()` is not returning a new `.connection`? Since the first condition would be false after `odbcCloseAll()`, the `.connection` object should be set by the line ".connection <<- odbcConnect("myDsn)". Right? I will really appreciate any insights into what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

You have closed the connection.  The first thing your function does is check to see if the connection exists.  If it does, it returns it.  If it doesn't, and only if it doesn't, it makes the connection.  Remove the `else` in your function as below, prevent it from closing a non-existent connection and it should work I believe.

```
library(RODBC)

getConnection <- function() {

  if (!exists('.connection', where=.GlobalEnv)) {
    .connection <<- odbcConnect("myDsn")
  }  
  if (class(try(sqlQuery(.connection, "SELECT 1"))) == "try-error") {
     if (!exists('.connection', where=.GlobalEnv)) {
       .connection <<- odbcConnect("myDsn")
     }
     else {
       odbcClose(.connection)         
     }
    .connection <<- odbcConnect("myDsn")
  }

  return(.connection)
}
```

EDIT:  Just removing the `else` should be fine:

```
getConnection <- function() {  
  if (!exists('.connection', where=.GlobalEnv)) {
    .connection <<- odbcConnect("myDsn")
  }  
  if (class(try(sqlQuery(.connection, "SELECT 1"))) == "try-error") {
    odbcClose(.connection)
    .connection <<- odbcConnect("myDsn")
  } 
  return(.connection)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried with the code that you posted, with the "else" removed but I still got an error: 
Error in sqlQuery(.connection, "SELECT 1") : 
  first argument is not an open RODBC channel
 Hide Traceback
 
 Rerun with Debug
 Error in odbcClose(.connection) : argument is not an open RODBC channel 

This time, I believe, the first condition fails; that is, R thinks that a connection exists. And the fails on the second condition where .connection is not an open RODBC channel.

Comment: Did you include the check for whether or not .connection exists?

Comment: I tried the code you posted with the second if(!exists... check inside of if(class(try... and I still got the `Error in sqlQuery(.connection, "SELECT 1") : 
  first argument is not an open RODBC channel 
 Error in odbcClose(.connection) : argument is not an open RODBC channel `

So it seems that after calling odbcCloseAll():  
- .connection still exists  
- .connection is not an open RODBC channel

Comment: Sorry... comment continued below:
`Error in sqlQuery(.connection, "SELECT 1") : 
  first argument is not an open RODBC channel 
 Error in odbcClose(.connection) : argument is not an open RODBC channel `

So it seems that after calling odbcCloseAll():  
- .connection still exists  
- .connection is not an open RODBC channel 
- `class(try(sqlQuery...` fails because it probably expects an open RODBC channel  to even try
- `else { odbcCose(...` also fails because .connection is not an RODBC channel.
Is my thinking correct?

Comment: That error shouldn't be possible. It's wrapped in a try.

Comment: I ran this in R studio console, manually checking each condition:
`exists('.connection', where=.GlobalEnv)` returns true even after `odbcCloseAll()`.    
`class(.connection)` returns "RODBC" even after `odbcCloseAll()`.    
`try(sqlQuery(.connection, "SELECT 1"))` returns 
`Error in sqlQuery(.connection, "SELECT 1") : 
  first argument is not an open RODBC channel` after odbcCloseAll()  
It seems that I should be checking for an open RODBC channel before calling the `class(try(sqlQuery...` not sure why the error is there despite the `try`. Thanks for your continued help.

Comment: Seems like a problem with `sqlQuery` in RODBC. I tried `sqlQuery(channel = .connection, query = "SELECT 1", errors = FALSE)` just to see if I get a -1 per the `sqlQuery` help page. I still got the Error. Seems like `sqlQuery` is intent on returning an error message no matter what I try.

Comment: I ran your script as-is before running anything else. It returned the error. If you can tell me how to post a log or screenshot on here, I would.

Comment: It's not returning that error.  Add `silent=TRUE` to the `try` call.